# How to login to the Microsoft RDP Client Control ActiveX using QAxContainer.QAxWidget() and PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, activex

everyone! Help me please with connecting to the Microsoft RDP Client Control using `QAxContainer.QAxWidget()` in Python and PyQt...

This is my code snippet:

```
QAx_RDP = QAxContainer.QAxWidget(self)
QAx_RDP.setControl('{54d38bf7-b1ef-4479-9674-1bd6ea465258}')
QAx_RDP.setProperty('Server', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
QAx_RDP.setProperty('UserName', 'user')
QAx_RDP.Connect()
```

All works fine, but I need to enter the password manually... My `QAx_RDP` object has the `AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword` property, but this property is not accessible. I tried to do it in two ways:

```
 1. QAx_RDP.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = "password"
 2. QAx_RDP.setProperty('ClearTextPassword', "password")
```

Neither of them works. How can I send a password programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have only done so with C++.

Imported RDP mstscax.dll with dumpcpp tool. Or you can do so with TYPELIBS = $$PWD/rdp/mstscax.dll in project.pro file and use produced definitions by including them in the project (see generated files). Then created ActiveX object rdpWidget out of MSTSCLib::MsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting (imported definition). You can use other versions as well.

```
// used parent widget for embedding ActiveX in it -- this
auto* rdpWidget = new MSTSCLib::MsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting(this);
```

Also called:

```
rdpWidget->show(); // what starts with lower-case is Qt method and uppercase is COM method
rdpWidget->SetUserName(userName);
MSTSCLib::IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings* pAdvSettings = rdpWidget->AdvancedSettings2();
pAdvSettings->SetClearTextPassword(password);
rdpWidget->Connect(); // don't forget!
```

Plus, there is quite a lot of event handling which is for specific purposes. It is a bit hard to cover everything in short reply but the ultimate source on that is [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). All this example is just a few lines but in reality there is many more. Should you have specific questions, you can ask them separately.

**EDIT**: update for another user who asks how to deal with dumpcpp import. Don't directly include it but rather do it by hand:

```
// Mind the structure of at least one RDP-related file in the project
// All includes

#define QAX_DUMPCPP_MSTSCLIB_NOINLINES // Important!
#include "mstscax.h" // see .pro file for TYPELIBS = $$PWD/rdp/mstscax.dll

// My code as above


// bottom of file: include own import file with all remaining functions
// with compile errors excluded by hand there is a handful of those
// complaining about private constructor of QObject or so
#include "mstscax_impl.cpp"
```

Comment: hi, i have used dumpcpp to generated .h and .cpp files(like mstsclib.h and mstsclib.cpp) for mstscax.dll.
but when i include mstsclib.h header file, many errors occur in my qt project. after googling, 
i think these codes cause these errors:
// stub for vtable-only interface
class IMsTscNonScriptable : public QAxObject {};

// stub for vtable-only interface
class IMsRdpClientNonScriptable : public QAxObject {};

have you ever met these errors ? or can you upload your codes about mstscax.dll ?  i will be appretiated if you can
 tell me your email address . thanks

Comment: @user2848932: I have updated my answer. Mind QAX_DUMPCPP_MSTSCLIB_NOINLINES.

Comment: thanks for you help ! i have done as what you said,but i still get errors.
after i include mstscax.h and add #define QAX_DUMPCPP_MSTSCLIB_NOINLINES, lnk2001 unresolved external symbol errors happens.
i think this error is associated with .cpp file. is the file mstscax_impl.cpp made by yourself ?
can i communicate with you by email? my email is libin0410@126.com. thank you again !